# Android EditText – Finding the redlined text and the list of suggested words

Tags: android, android-edittext, spell-checking, autosuggest

I have an `EditText` view with the spell checker activated. If there is a misspelled word, the word is redlined and a list of suggestions is displayed in a drop down menu. How can I programmatically find the list of misspelled words and the suggestion list for each of them?
Note it is `EditText`, not `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Comment: To the person who down voted my question: Thank you very much for taking time to read it. Would you care to comment why you down voted it? I spent several hours doing research before posting the question on SO with the hope that somebody out there might know the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an easy way to find the suggestions:

```
Spannable str = myEditText.getText(); 
SuggestionSpan[] spanned = str.getSpans(startIndex, endIndex, SuggestionSpan.class);
```

If `spanned` is not empty, there is an error in the text between `startIndex` and `endIndex`. By changing the values of these indices, it will be possible to find which word is erroneous. Each item in the spanned array has a field called `mSuggestions`, which is an array of strings and provides the suggested words for the erroneous word.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a guess, but I'd take a look at the [Android spellchecker classes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/textservice/SpellCheckerSession.html) and finally at the [EditText sourcecode](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/EditText.java).

The way it could work is by simply getting the text using `getText()` and then run the spellchecker again by yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much Sebastian! Rerunning the spell checker can work. I looked at the `EditText` and `TextView` source as you suggested and was able to find an easier way. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Wow, `SuggestionSpan` - didn't know about that. Cool!